# Unity mirror and webcam streaming WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, webcam, multiplayer, unity3d-mirror

I have a project in witch I use mirror (unet 2.0 :P) to make a simple low poly WebGL game  in unity. the game works great. Now I want to send a webcamstream over the network. I want to do this for every player.

I managed to get the cam working locally. Now I want to get it to run via the network. I made a Colors32[] array witch holds the image, it also works locally. Only If I try to send it over the network using a [Command] function I get the message that my packet is to large. I heard that splitting a package gives a lot of latency so I tried this solution [sendTextures](https://unitylist.com/p/fdt/u-Texture-Send-Receive) but it doesn't play nice with mirror. I only get one frame (if I'm lucky) if I turn my networkmanager on.

Do you guys have any pointers for me to get it working?

This is the code I have so far:

```
public class WebCamScript : NetworkBehaviour
{
    static WebCamTexture camTexture;
    Color32[] data;

    private int width = 640, height = 480;

    public GameObject screen;

    void Start()
    {
        screen = GameObject.Find("screen");

        if (camTexture == null)
            camTexture = new WebCamTexture(width, height);

        data = new Color32[width * height];

        if (!camTexture.isPlaying)
            camTexture.Play();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {
        CmdSendCam(data.Length, camTexture.GetPixels32(data));
   }

   [Command]
   void CmdSendCam(int length, Color32[] receivedImage)
   {
       /*       
        Texture2D t = new Texture2D(width, height);
    
        t.SetPixels32(receivedImage);
        t.Apply();
        screen.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = t;
       */
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is your first go at this.  Video (eg, web cam) Streaming is not nearly as simple as just sending a sequence of jpegs.  You generally want to encode it (eg, FFMpeg, or nvenc) so you get a *much* better data rate.